# WooCommerce product set_product_url method does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, product

have this issue :

```
$product = wc_get_product( $productid );

if($product && $product->get_type() == 'external'){

    // 'IF' CHECKED AND WORK, I AM HERE  
    $product->set_product_url( 'http:/linkto download' );
    $product->set_button_text( 'Download' );

}
```

I want to update **product_url** link but not work, why ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using any WooCommerce product setter method on the product instance object, you need to **save the data** to database using the [`save()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_save) at the end, like:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $productid );

if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) && $product->is_type( 'external' ) ){

    // 'IF' CHECKED AND WORK, I AM HERE  
    $product->set_product_url( 'http:/linkto download' );
    $product->set_button_text( 'Download' );

    $product->save();
}
```

This time it will work.